# Solr admin portal HTTP ERROR 404 Issue

Tags: solr

We are using `solr 6.6.2` with `Sitecore 9.0.2` and `https://localhost:8989/solr/` working fine.
Yesterday evening suddenly I was getting

```
HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /solr/. Reason:

    Not Found
Caused by:
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Error processing the request. CoreContainer is either not initialized or shutting down.
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:321)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I also verified `solr` services up and running, there are no schema changes happened.

Comment: Please check solr logs for detailed error, usually real error at the last of stack trace, one more thing please validate solr.xml present or not or if present then check this must not be corrupted.

Comment: This error indicates a configuration problem with one or more of your Solr cores. Which index are you trying to access? In the Solr web admin, are you able to enumerate all of your cores from the CoreAdmin tool? Have there been any recent changes to the core configuration? If this is the problem you can unload the core and reconfigure using a heathy core as a template.

Answer (score 0):

This issue usually comes when the core is not configured properly, try to delete the core which is not configured rightly and create the core again then rebuild `Sitecore` indexes again.

Check the below link as well:

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/walkthrough--setting-up-solr.html

Answer (score 0):

I did face this issue and for me, it was due to the `corrupted solr.xml`. I did compare it with other running instances and got to know the issue with the `solr.xml` file and the core folder getting corrupted.

To resolve it you can try the following steps.

1. Check the `core.properties` for the index.
2. Validate the `Solr.xml` file. It might get corrupted.

Hope it helps!